# I want to send text entered in modal in React.js to Backend

Tags: reactjs

I am using React.js to create the front-end side of a web application that can control home appliances.

What I want to achieve is
I want to send the text entered in the modal to Backend.
At that time, I want to prevent the screen reload.

Issue is
When I put the text in the modal and press the Submit button, the page reload happens and I can't see what was sent in the console.
Please see the video below for details.

https://youtu.be/_ppCNBTBIvc

AddRoomModal.js

```
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';


const cookies = new Cookies();


const AddRoomModal = (props) => {

  const [room_name, setRoomName] = useState("");

  const addRoom = (e) => {
    setRoomName(e.target.value);
  }

  const clickSubmit = (e) => {
    AddRoom(e.target.value);
  }

  const building_state = useSelector(state => state.building_state.building_state);

  console.log(building_state);

  const url_forgetroomname = {
    "condo": "aaa.com",
    "office": "bbb.com",
    "house": "ccc.com"
   }[building_state]

  const AddRoom = async(data) => {
    console.log("Body sent to server", {
    home_rooms: room_name, 
  })
    await axios.post(url_forgetroomname,
      {
        home_rooms: room_name, 
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
        },
      })
      .then(result => {
        alert('Succeded add room!');
        console.log('Succeded add room!');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        alert('Missed add room!');
        console.log(err);
        console.log('Missed add room!');
      });
  }

  const getRoomName = async(data) => {
    await axios.get(url_forgetroomname,
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
        },
      })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result.data)
        setRoomName(result.data.home_rooms);  
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }


  return (
    <>
      <Modal show={props.show}>
      <Modal.Body className="light_modal_body" >
      <div className="light_modal_body">     
        <div className="range-container col-12">
        </div>
        <h3>Add Room</h3>
        <form>
        <input type="text" onChange={addRoom} value={room_name}/>
        <div className="done_button">
          <button className='btn btn-block btn-primary' type="submit" onClick={clickSubmit}>
          OK
          </button>
        </div>
        </form>
        <div className="done_button">
          <button onClick={props.handleHide} className='btn btn-block btn-danger'>Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
export default AddRoomModal;
```

HeaderForSettingGetRoomName.js

```
import AddRoomModal from '../AddRoomModal';

const cookies = new Cookies();

const HeaderForSettingGetRoomName = (props) => {
  const isLoggedInOn = useSelector(state => state.user.isLoggedIn);

  // modal
  const [show, setShow] = useState();

  // Show Modal
  const handleShow = () => {
    setShow(true);
  }
  // Hide modal
  const handleHide = () => {
    setShow(false);
  }



  const building_state = useSelector(state => state.building_state.building_state);

  console.log(building_state);


    return (
      <div>
        <AddRoomModal
          show={show} handleHide={handleHide}
        />
        <div className="header">
              <Link to={`/setting`} className="">        <img className="header_menu_back_leftside" src={ic_back} alt="" />
              </Link>
              <img className="header_logo" src={logo_image} />
              <img className="ic_add_white" src={ic_add_white} onClick={handleShow}/>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }

  export default HeaderForSettingGetRoomName;
```

Comment: use `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the default form behaviour (submitting the form) by calling preventDefault on the submit event

```
const clickSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    AddRoom(e.target.value);
}
```